# Endless loop XML

Tags: jquery, xml

I am reading and saving data to xml.

Reading by script, and saving "contenedor":

```
<div id="contenedor">
    <script>escribir("CONTENEDOR");</script>
</div>
```

And of course, when it loads, generate a endless loop.

How can I make the script to load inside "contenedor" but not saving the `<script>`?

I tried this:

```
<script>$(function(){$('contenedor').append("<script>escribir('CONTENEDOR')</script>")});;</script>
    <div id="contenedor">
</div>
```

but it didn't work!

EDIT:

Sorry, this is escribir function:

```
function escribir(nombre){
document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INFO")[0].getElementsByTagName(nombre)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

I figured that i get this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

I retyped the line, not copy and paste but still getting the error!

pd: Sorry for my english !

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question is very unclear. Why are you trying to write a script within a div? Also, your jQuery is wrong (it should be `$('#contenedor')`, etc.). Finally, you don't provide the source for `escribir()`, so it's impossible for us to tell what you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

You have forgotten to add # to the jquery selector. Try somethink like this:

```
$('#contenedor').append(ecribir('...'));
```